# Python - Questrade API - Redeeming access token problem

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a python program to retrieve stock market data from Questrade and I'm having some difficulty redeeming an 'access token'.

My understanding was that we can simply append the token we receive from the 'manual authorization' step to the Questrade URL.

My code is the following:

```py
       import requests
       ...
       QT_URL = 'https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='
       RetValue = '123456789'
       ...
       Results = requests.get(QT_URL+RetValue) 
       print(Results)
```

My results are:

```py
       <Response [400]>
```

Thanks.

Comment: In OAuth2, an "*access token*" is **not at all** the same as a "*refresh token*" and they cannot be used interchangeably - please make sure you understand this and are using the correct endpoints/terminology as such before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out so if anyone is looking for the solution, here it is.  I know the terminology might not be correct but it is more to describe the process.

Every week, you need to log into Questrade and generate a token that is good for 1 week but can only be used once and is used to get a file (json I believe) containing, among other things, an access token that is used to make data requests and a refresh token.

The access token is valid for 30 minutes and once it has expired, you need to use the refresh token to generate a new access token and refresh token.

Every 30 minutes you need to use the refresh token to generate a new data access token and refresh token and repeat the cycle until the weekly token has expired.

I hope this explanation helps anyone else who is a bit confused about the process.